# Null value while doing createcriteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, createcriteria

```
def c = Employee.createCriteria()
return c.list {
  } as Set;
```

The above code is returning me all the objects of the table.

But when I am trying to filter it like, I am getting null values :

```
def c = Employee.createCriteria()
    return c.list {
    'eq'('id', 604931)
} as Set;
```

(or)

```
def c = Employee.createCriteria()
    return c.list {
    'between'('updatededOn', startDate, endDate)
} as Set;
```

What I exactly want is to retrieve all the rows from the Employee table where updated_on is between startDate and endDate. startDate and endDate are Date objects.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
def employees = Employee.withCriteria {
    between('updatededOn', startDate, endDate)
}
```

Comment: Other than not casting to a `Set` (which I don't think has any effect on this), this looks equivalent to the question's example.  `createCriteria().list{}` and `withCriteria` achieve the same thing, and `'between'` and `between` should have the same functionality in this context.